# NSFaultingOrderedSet in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, core-data

I am using CoreData objects in iOS.

A product has subproducts

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *subProducts;
```

For some reason, for one of the products , instead of getting a NSOrderedSet, I am getting a _NSFaultingMutableSet. I cant use objectAtIndex method on that object but I can iterate over it using a for.

What is that _NSFaultingMutableSet class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `_NSFaultingMutableSet` is a private CoreData subclass of `NSMutableSet`. Are you sure your .xcdatamodel declares the relationship as ordered? Just because your code declares the property as `NSOrderedSet` doesn't mean it necessarily is; that's controlled entirely by the data model.

Comment: No, i am not sure. Where do i declare it as ordered?

Comment: @Tony: In the data model, which is the file that has the extension `.xcdatamodel`.

Answer (score 0):

`NSFaultingOrderedSet` is not an official API. You could try making sure you have the right class like this:

```
NSOrderedSet *subProducts = (NSOrderedSet *)product.subProducts;
Product *firstSubProduct = [subProducts objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: That's exactly my code, but for some reason product.subProducts; returns _NSFaultingMutableSet

Comment: The cast does absolutely nothing.